# Show quotes with echo inside bash -c

Tags: bash, quoting, escape-characters

I am trying to echo `I say "Hello, World!"` with `bash -c`. This is (some of) what I have tried:

```
$ bash -c "echo I say \"Hello, World"'!'"\""
$ bash -c "echo I say "'"'"Hello, World"'!'"\""
$ bash -c "echo I say """Hello, World"""'!'
$ bash -c $'echo I say \"Hello, World!\"'
$ bash -c 'echo I say "Hello, World!"'
```

They all print

```
I say Hello, World!
```

How can I show the quotes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you have nested quotes, which makes quoting somewhat involved. Since you don't have a "comprehensive" quote around your arguments to `echo`, all your attempts (except for your 3rd attempt<sup>(1)</sup>) are actually passing three arguments to `echo`, which are all subject to [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html):

- `I`
- `say`
- `Hello, World!`

The key point is that upon interpretation of the "outer" command, the outer quotes of the argument to `bash -c` are removed. The inner quotes remain, either because they are escaped or because they are of different type than the outer ones.

Then, when the `bash` instance you explicitly called processes that argument (the "inner" command), it itself performs quote-removal when interpreting the arguments to the `echo` call. Thus, the quotes you put around `Hello, World!` will ensure that this is considered *one* argument to `echo`, but be removed in the same process (and thereby lost to `echo`).

Since you don't need variable expansion in the ("inner") `echo` command, I would go with the single-quote syntax as follows:

```
bash -c 'echo "I say \"Hello, World\"!"'
```

That way you are passing one single argument to `echo`, and the quote-escaping inside the double-quotes will work as expected.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> In the 3rd attempt you show, you are actually passing 2 arguments to `bash -c`:

- `echo I say Hello,` and
- `World!`

leading to *four* arguments to `echo` seen by the "inner" command. This is because your attempt to "interrupt" the outer double-quotes with `"""` doesn't work that way - instead, the first of these double-quotes mean that the starting double-quote of the `bash -c` argument is closed after the space. This is then seen as being followed by an empty double-quoted string, and then by an *unquoted* `Hello,`. All these are concatenated because there is no space in between them.

Then, since the space following is unprotected, the outer `bash` will now consider the remainder a second argument, starting with the (again unquoted) `World`, a double-quoted empty string, and then an opened-but-unclosed double-quoted string containing `'!'`. The fact that it is not correctly closed is masked by the error message you should receive about an "event not found", since the starting double-quote makes the following single-quote merely a character to-be-printed, whereby the `!` is no longer protected from interpretation as history reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont care about POSIX-compliance, you can work around the problem by adding `-e` to `echo` and print the ascii-codes for `"` which would be `\x22` (in hex) or `\042` (in octal).

`bash -c 'echo -e "I say \x22Hello, World\x22"'`

`bash -c 'echo -e "I say \042Hello, World\042"'`